# Marklogic Eclipse Setup

Tags: eclipse, xquery, marklogic

I have been trying to setup eclipse with marklogic to use it as my xquery editor. I am following this link as per Marklogic: http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup.

I did all the steps multiple times but I always get this error while run my default.xqy file:

> **Execution failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No content-type header in part**.

Steps:

1. Installed MLC,
2. Installed Eclipse Helios 3.6.2
3. Configured XDBC server from admin console and use port as 8025.
4. In Eclipse, URL used for XCC: xcc://localhost:8025

Comment: Which version of MarkLogic?