# Marklogic Xquery setup on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xquery, marklogic

I followed the instructions on https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup for Xquery on Eclipse.

My drop-in folder looks like this. It currently contains all&only those unzipped from xqdt-dropin.zip as instructed on https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup:

[image]

The jars in the `dropins\eclipse\pluginsplugin` directory are these:
[image]

After these, when/if I look to install the plugins from http://developer.marklogic.com/eclipse/xqdt/milestone/latest/ on Eclipse  (Help > Install New Software… of Eclipse), I see that “All items are installed”.

I’m getting the following error to my Xqueries:

```
Execution failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No content-type header in part
```

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup is recommending 
Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) or Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo). I’m using Eclipse Mars and Marklogic version 8.0-5.2. Is this a version issue?

[This](http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2015-September/017993.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520481/marklogic-eclipse-setup) seem to be the same Q.

Hopw to resolve this?

TIA.

//--------------------------

Additional note:

I later tried installing `XQDT Core (Required) (Incbuator)` under `XQuery Development Tools Feature` 
from http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/incubator/repository/xquery/milestones/. However, Eclipse required to install/upgrade/downgrade some of the existing jars for this installation and i didn't go that way (cancelled this installation) My environment now is same as before-- the one i described here above.

Comment: My understanding is that the Eclipse tools have not been updated for years. I would recommend trying out the MarkLogic package for Sublime Text, which is more up to date. There is also an XQuery extension for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @wst is this an Eclipse version issue? 

i wouldn't mind downgrading Eclipse as opposed to patching it up-- this is a new project. 

but if it's on Marklogic side, thats something else.

Comment: It's neither. The Xquery Toolkit is simply way out of date. You could downgrade Eclipse to an older version to make it work, but it would still not support features added to MarkLogic over the past several years.

Comment: @wst  Is it just the "Subline Text Plugin" or "XQDT for Eclipse and Marklogic Fork" as well, on https://developer.marklogic.com/code/xqdt it also looks "promising"

Comment: It looks like there has been some activity updating XQDT in a development branch (https://github.com/mcrosier/ML-XQDT/tree/xquery-dev). The most recent commits are still quite old, but it might work better than when I last used it. However, I have used the Sublime Text plugin (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkLogic) and I can confirm it works well.

Comment: @wst ok- thx. i'll check these out.

Comment: Not really an answer, so mentioning this as a comment: you can also consider using oXygen, which has capabilities to run, and even debug code in MarkLogic, and also provides elaborate support for other XML technologies. Also worth mentioning, is Query Console that comes with MarkLogic. MarkLogic 9 (currently available via Early Access) provides a few interesting enhancements for it..

Comment: More to the point: can you report which XCC jar version you are using? It is recommended to take latest. You can download it here: http://developer.marklogic.com/products/xcc

Comment: @grtjn is any of these bypassing Xquery? Java API is what i'll be using in the end, but Java (NodeJS or any other ) itself is using XQuery to talk to ML. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/searchdev says so- if i didn't miss anthing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Java Client API is an abstraction layer, and mostly communicates via REST. XQDT and XCC are much more down to earth, and use a proprietary protocol to execute code on the server..

Comment: @grtjn It's an architectural Q. what does ML spit out-- XQuery only or can i also get XML output directly from ML engine? From what i've found out so far, it's XQuery only, and the APIs (Java, Rest, .NET, NodeJS, ..) are processing on that XQuery output from the ML engine.

Comment: Getting a little too detailed for a comment actually. MarkLogic has a parser that can execute XQuery, XSLT and Server-Side JavaScript. You can store XML, JSON, Text, and Binary. Whatever way you use to connect, it is going to run one of those three languages (or a combi potentially), and return the data you asked for (in the 4 base types mentioned). What in terms of arch is best way of connecting to ML depends on goals and principles. Most people use REST apis these days, and we have some Client libraries for that. That is unrelated to Eclipse though..